# Srobbin pageslide edit fail. Please

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okey here is this Very good jquery slider.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide

and what i have done is

http://mbu.mn/test

So here is the broblem. Think this is an iPad screen so i click on a link it slides in. and when i click on home button it returns to home page. if i see it on FF15 it looks just the way i wanted but on Safari, Chrome it looks overflown to the left. If there anyway to fix it it really help me a lot. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if content to be loaded is dynamic it's messing with page styling, on the other hand modal, or programmatic load which is attached to existing element seems to avoid similar problems. btw the plugin seems a little bit outdated, not updated for more than 6 months as for now. Also there is some issues with touch based devices and clicking on document to close.